# I can't print image of v-img in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing

I'm trying to use printd and vue-html-to-paper to print Vue component.
But the print out only text element. If I use v-img tag, the image doesn't print out.
But img tag works. like .

Comment: Can you add code snippets? Or create a jsfiddle for better understanding

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Finally, I used img tag instead of v-img to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path is correct and you follow this style:

```
data(){
    return{
    imgUrl: require('@path/to/hi.jpg')
}
```